# the minimal generating set for the derived subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a group of order $p^n$ such that $d(G/Z(G))=t$, ($d(X)$ denote  the minimal number of generators of $X$). Is there any bound for $d(G')$($G'$ is the derived subgroup of $G$) in terms of $t$?
Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I have no proof of this answer, but computer calculations strongly indicate that the answer is no, there is no such bound.

The exponent $p$-class $k$ quotient $G$ of the free group of rank $2$ appears to have $d(G/Z(G))=2$ and $d(G') = k(k-1)/2$. I checked this up to $d=12$ for various $p$, and it appears to be independent of $p$.

If $|G/Z(G)| = p^m$, then we have $|G'| = p^l$ with $l \le tm$, and hence $d(G') \le tm$ but there might be better bounds than that.